# Rails isolated Engine with dependencies from main_app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I have an app that consists of a main rails 3.2 app which acts as the base and an admin part. I also have an isolated engine which handles the non logged in part of the site.

Naturally, the engine has a lot of dependencies on classes from the main app. This makes it hard to test it in isolation. I've seen an example somewhere of a sort of 'bridge' between the main app and the engine, but I can't remember where.

I guess what I'm really asking is how do you handle these kinds of dependencies, can you minimize them, and how do you test the engine? As I've understood you run the test from the dummy-app, but since I have a whole lot of dependencies that doesn't work out that well.

Are there any good resources on best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So naturally the engines has a lot of dependencies on classes from the
>   main app.

**This is not the idea behind Rails Engines**. An Engine should be able to function on its own for the most part. If the code project you are building is dependent on the Main Rails application, then you are building an extension. If this is true, check out the Spree project. It's one main Rails Application, with multiple extensions that are dependent on the Spree application.

https://github.com/spree

If you are looking for examples for true Rails Engines, check out these,
https://github.com/westonplatter/questionnaire_engine
https://github.com/radar/forem/
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/

Full disclosure, I helped code QuestionnaireEngine.

Comment: Doesn't the Spree project use a Rails Engine for each extension? Such as spree_review. Is that an reasonable use of Engines? I also want to separate code as an engine which is dependent on the container app (or on a 'core' engine)